# Control close event pyglet

Tags: python-3.x, events, pyglet

I have a program that has multiple windows in pyglet, and I want to make one window unclosable, rather to set its visibility to false. Is there a way I can access the event handle for close, to make it instead of closing the window, possibly return a bool or a string like "should close."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer to my own question, first define a custom event loop with `window_event_loop = pyglet.app.EventLoop()`, then create a handler for .event for the event loop

```
@window_event_loop.event
    def on_window_close(window):
        # Extra code here
        return pyglet.event.EVENT_HANDLED
```